# How do I find the duplicate number in a list provided and print that number?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I would like to write a short Python function that will detect the duplicate number in a list of integers and print out that number to standard output.  The input 5;0,1,2,3,0 is generated by these lines already:

import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line,

And I am wondering whether I could use the following code (part of the above for loop) to get the desired output of "0":

```
seen = set()
for num in line:
    if num in seen:
        print num
    else:
        seen.add(num)
```

So far this gives me the output:
5;0,1,2,3,0
,
,
,
0

I just need to get rid of the comma lines and keep the 0...
This is for Python in general, not necessarily Python 3.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you need **print (num)**.  Is that the problem?

Comment: That error usually has a specific error message complaining about parentheses, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: The code runs for me in Python 2.7; thanks TigerHawkT3.

Comment: I am trying to do it on Python 3, yes

Comment: I guess you're using an older version of Python 3 that doesn't have that specific error message. Anyway, the fix is simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with this short code

```
In[43]: a = [0,1,2,3,0]
        print [j for j, i in enumerate(a) if j in a[i+1:]]
Output
[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this would work well too...would this syntax work for Python 3?  The compiler gives me an error at the "for" expression.

Answer (score 0):

One little correction: you want to add the number to the set **seen** if you *haven't* seen it before:

```
line = [5,0,1,2,3,0]
seen = set()
for num in line:
    if num in seen:
        print num
    else:
        seen.add(num)
```

This produces the desired output of a single 0.

Answer (score 0):

A small refinement to the code from Alexis G which makes the line more generic:

```
a=[1,6,2,4,6,5]
print [j for i, j in enumerate(a) if j in a[i+1:]]
[6]

a=[1,6,2,4,6,5,2]
print [j for i, j in enumerate(a) if j in a[i+1:]]
[6, 2]

a = ['a','d','c','d','f','b','f']
print [j for i, j in enumerate(a) if j in a[i+1:]]
['d', 'f']
```